# Overlaying G-plots

Tags: r, overlay, python-ggplot

I have to overlay two plots but am having troubling with naming them and going about plotting them. I've tried doing the code below for the two plots I want to compare.

```
geom_plot1=ggplot(data=DataframeName,mapping=aes(x=ColumnNameOnly))
geom_plot2=ggplot(data=DataframeName,mapping=aes(x=ColumnNameOnly))
```

Then from there I used:

```
ggplot(DataFrame) + 
  geom_plot1(aes(x=Column1, y=Column2)) +
  geom_plot2(aes(x=Column1,y=Column3)) + 
  ...FormattingCommands...
```

I know very well that putting the name at the beginning of the first code is not how you go about naming them, so if anyone knows how to name the plots and then overlay the plots I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question will get more attention if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). At least, provide sample data and describe what you are trying to plot.

Answer (score 0):

with ggplot you can stack layers of different data sources and geometries* like:

```
ggplot() +
    geom_point(data = dataframe_1, aes(x = ..., y = ...)) +
    geom_point(data = dataframe_2, aes(x = ..., y = ...))
```

- technically at least (may produce conceptually nonsensical charts though)